# Is it possible to return an instance of a non-movable, non-copyable type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In VS2013 update 5, I've got this:

```
class Lock
{
public:
    Lock(CriticalSection& cs) : cs_(cs)
    {}

    Lock(const Lock&) = delete;
    Lock(Lock&&) = delete;
    Lock& operator=(const Lock&) = delete;
    Lock& operator=(Lock&&) = delete;

    ~Lock()
    {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&(cs_.cs_));
    }

private:
    CriticalSection& cs_;
};


class CriticalSection
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION cs_;
public:
    CriticalSection(const CriticalSection&) = delete;
    CriticalSection& operator=(const CriticalSection&) = delete;
    CriticalSection(CriticalSection&&) = delete;
    CriticalSection& operator=(CriticalSection&&) = delete;

    CriticalSection()
    {
        InitializeCriticalSection(&cs_);
    }

    ~CriticalSection()
    {
        DeleteCriticalSection(&cs_);
    }

    // Usage:  auto lock = criticalSection.MakeLock();
    Lock MakeLock()
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(&cs_);
        return Lock(*this);
    }
}
```

`MakeLock` returns an instance of a non-movable, non-copyable type. And this seems to work ok. But, Visual Studio intellisense does underline the return in red with a warning that Lock's move constructor can't be referenced as it is a deleted function.

I'm trying to understand why this works and if it is standard conforming C++ or just something peculiar to MSVC. I guess the return works because the need to construct the returned value can be optimized away, so the intellisense warning warns about something that doesn't - in practice - actually happen.

I think I read somewhere that that C++ would standardize on ensuring that return value optimizations would always happen.

So, is this conforming C++ code and will it continue to work in future compilers?

P.S. I realize `std::mutex` and a `std::lock_guard` might replace this.

Comment: The code would be ill-formed in standard C++, though there is [proposed extension](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html) that would make the code behave as expected.

Comment: This seems to indicate that that extension (P0135R0) has been approved. I guess I need to wait for a C++17 compiler. https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/11/kona-standards-meeting-trip-report

Comment: No, P0135 is in early stages and far from "approval". While it seems to be very positively received, it's nowhere near its final form yet. Vendors generally only implement obvious defect reports (even before approval), or things in the actual working draft that go beyond the last published standard.

Comment: `return {*this};` rather than `return Lock(*this);` does what you want prior to C++17.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If that compiles, it is a bug in the compiler.  VC2015 correctly fails to compile it.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {}
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
};


Foo Bar()
{
    return Foo();
}
```

Gives me:

```
xxx.cpp(327): error C2280: 'Foo::Foo(Foo &&)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

and g++ 4.9 says:

```
error : use of deleted function 'Foo::Foo(Foo&&)'
```

The standard is very clear that a copy constructor or move constructor must exist and be accessible, even if RVO means it is not invoked.

Comment: Correct. I have checked, even g++-5.1 also doesn't compile this code. Results in: `error: use of deleted function ‘Lock::Lock(Lock&&)’`.

Answer (score 12):

In C++17, the code in Martin Bonner's answer is legal.

The compiler is not only permitted, but also obligated to elide the copy. Live examples for [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ef5e349006c6393) and [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db158aa9a368942e). C++17 6.3.2/2 (emphasis mine):

> [...] [Note: A return statement can involve an invocation of a constructor to perform a copy or move of the operand **if it is not a prvalue** or if its type differs from the return type of the function. A copy operation associated with a return statement may be elided or converted to a move operation if an automatic storage duration variable is returned (10.9.5). — end note]

A prvalue here means as much as a temporary. For exact definitions and a lot of examples, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

In C++11, this is indeed illegal. But it is easily remedied, by using brace initialization in the return statement, you construct the return value at the call site location, perfectly bypassing the requirement of an often-elided copy constructor. C++11 6.6.3/2:

> [...] A return statement with a braced-init-list initializes the object or reference to be returned from the function by copy-list-initialization (8.5.4) from the specified initializer list. [...]

Copy-list-initialization means that only the constructor is called. No copy/move constructors are involved.

Live examples for [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fdfe4630b1eacf4) and [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8347624a49bab85).
From Visual Studio compiler version 16.14 up, setting the correct language standard [allows this code to be compiled](https://godbolt.org/z/BOU8ZL).

Returning non-copyable objects like this is a very powerful construct for returning e.g. `std::lock_guard`s from functions (allowing you to easily keep a `std::mutex` member private) etc.

Answer (score 1):

As of MSVC v19.14, MSVC (aka Visual Studio) also implements the C++17 behavior of allowing `return` of a non-copyable, non-movable object in cases where the RVO applies: https://godbolt.org/z/fgUFdf

As rubenvb's answer indicates, this means that GCC, Clang, and MSVC all support this C++17 behavior: https://godbolt.org/z/Hq_GyG