# Returning non-copyable non-movable object with explicit constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

If we have a non-movable, non-copyable class with non-explicit constructor, we can return it and use as follows (in C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
class NonCop
{
public:
    /*non explicit*/ NonCop(int a, int b) : number(a + b) {}
    NonCop(const NonCop&) = delete;
    int number;
};

NonCop get_non_cop()
{
    return {1, 2};
}

int main()
{
    NonCop &&nc = get_non_cop();
    std::cout << "three: " << nc.number << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However if the constructor is explicit, it doesn't work. Is there any method of doing this in C++11/C++14 with no modifications in `NonCop`?

Currently I'm using workaround with deriving from NonCop with wrapper that "deexplicits" the constructor but it doesn't seem very pretty.

Comment: Dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263916/is-it-possible-to-return-an-instance-of-a-non-movable-non-copyable-type) for C++11/14.  Do note that in C++17 guaranteed copy elision will make the code compile.

Comment: I'm baffled that that actually works, and also baffled that you want to do this. It's pretty awful of you not to allow the caller to return the same object untouched. I hope this is just an academic exercise and not something you actually want to do.

Comment: @Mehrdad: In C++03 you could also bind a temporary object to a const reference which extends the lifetime of the object to the end of the scope. I think it is used by scopeguard in folly.

Comment: @knivil: I'm aware... I'm not sure what the relevance of that was though? I was talking about letting a caller *return* the value, not merely *use* it.

Comment: It is not pure academic. folly use template magic (function template parameters to derive class template parameters) and binds the created object to a base class reference (that explanation may be wrong). Very handy if you do not have the keyword `auto` and do not know the type of your lambda expression. E.g. Visual Studio 2010 supports `lambda` but no `auto`.

Comment: @knivil: It's exactly what I want to do. `NonCop` is a lock that holds a mutex. It would be better if it just supported move construction, but it's in the external lib and it doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.  There is no mechanism to call explicit constructors while returning from a function in C++11 or 14 without having an implicit move or copy (that the compiler will certainly elide).

In C++17 you can just type `return NonCop(1,2);` and due to "guaranteed elision" it will no longer require a move or copy constructor.

---

But this is C++, so yes, I can make your code work with zero additional overhead.  By cheating, and returning a different type.

```
template<class T>
struct implicit_construct:T {
  template<class...Ts>
  implicit_construct(Ts&&...ts):
    T(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) // note: this is an EXPLICIT construction
  {}
};

implicit_construct<NonCop> get_non_cop()
{
  return {1, 2};
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3367efcfeaa979f0).

An `implicit_construct<NonCop>` derives from a `NonCop`, so you can store the return value in a `NonCop&&`.

---

If you are writing `NonCop` yourself, then what I'd do is add:

```
 struct explicit_construct_t {};
 // ...
 struct NonCop {
   // ...
   template<class...Ts>
   NonCop( explicit_construct_t, Ts&&...ts ):
     NonCop( std::forward<Ts>(ts)... )
  {}
  // ...
};
```

which means you can call explicit constructors by prefixing it with a `explicit_construct_t` to call them implicitly:

```
NonCop get_non_cop() {
  return {explicit_construct_t{}, 1, 2};
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunatelly, in this context you can't return the temporary object, since in a return by value expression the compiler requires that the object's copy constructor is accessible, even if this object is going to be copy elided in the end. However, you could return a `std::unique_ptr` instead of concrete object.

```
std::unique_ptr<NonCop> get_non_cop() {
    return std::make_unique<NonCop>(1, 2);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c90b061bfbeff938)

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I need this for mutex locking and making an additional allocation each time is not acceptable.

Comment: @peper0: Then don't use a real heap allocator. Use a pool allocator or somesuch.